# Need to add another decimal space so the number has a .00 f.e., not .0

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple trapezoid area calculator, but I need to upload it to a website to get graded and the site gives me no credit due to the fact that numbers have 1 less zeroes after the initial result, and they also don't round up if it happens to not give an exact number. How can I solve this problem?

```py
b1 = float(input())
b2 = float(input())
h = float(input())
sq_area = (b1 + b2) * h / 2
print(sq_area)
```

[IMG of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoaSH.png)

Comment: `print("%.2f" % (sq_area,))`

Comment: Thank you for the quick and correct response, Alex! Worked out wonderfully. I hope you have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the three dominant methods for formatted floating point in Python:

```
b1 = 10.0
b2 = 12.0
h = 2.3
sq_area = (b1 + b2) * h / 2
print(f'{sq_area:.02f}', '{:.02f}'.format(sq_area), '%.02f' % sq_area)
```

Prints:

```
25.30 25.30 25.30
```

The methods:

1. `f'{sq_area:.02f}` is an f string covered in [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/);
2. `'{:.02f}'.format(sq_area)` using the `.format` string method covered in [PEP 3101](https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/);
3. `'%.02f' % sq_area` the [legacy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) `%` operator with printf type formatting.

The f string method and .format method use Python's [Format Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) and the `%` method uses a subset of specifiers similar to [printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

Answer (score -1):

Google f-string formatting and/or format specifiers. As this is clearly homework, I think it would be wrong to simply provide you with the answer.

As an alternative, f-string formatting in conjunction with padding might work, too.